# Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : there are aliased coefficients in the model

Tags: r, anova, diagnostics

For my experiment, I have **3 independent variables**: *trial type, sex and gaming experience* (all of which are categorical).

I have one **dependent variable:** *proportion of correct trials* (which is continuous).

When I tried running a 3-way ANOVA, the assumptions were not met, and so I used an **aligned-rank transformation ANOVA**.

```
m1 <- art(Proportioncorrect ~ Videogamefrequency + Biologicalsex + + Trialtype + Videogamefrequency:Biologicalsex + Videogamefrequency:Trialtype + Biologicalsex:Trialtype + Biologicalsex:Trialtype:Videogamefrequency, data = Gaming)
```

The model gave me the error:

```
Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :  
there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

Could anyone give me a helping hand?

My data is here:

```
structure(list(ID = c("P_200214123342", "P_200224092247", "P_200219163622", 
"P_200220130332", "P_200219091823", "P_200225184226", "P_200219123120", 
"P_200219175102", "P_200214103155", "P_200219111605", "P_200217101213", 
"P_200219102411", "P_200221101028", "P_200220145557", "P_200225171612", 
"P_200224092247", "P_200219163622", "P_200220130332", "P_200214123342", 
"P_200219091823", "P_200225184226", "P_200219123120", "P_200219175102", 
"P_200214103155", "P_200219111605", "P_200217101213", "P_200219102411", 
"P_200221101028", "P_200220145557", "P_200225171612"), Trialtype = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Beaconed", 
"Probe"), class = "factor"), Proportioncorrect = c(0.729727660699102, 
1.33933990048532, 0.729727660699102, 1.075862200454, 0.578378233982015, 
1.16808048521424, 1.33933990048532, 1.13531397797248, 1.28700221758657, 
1.13531397797248, 1.28700221758657, 1.13531397797248, 1.28700221758657, 
1.28700221758657, 1.20358829695229, 0.297711691252463, 0.160690652951911, 
0.147197653346961, 0.0667161517509908, 0.080085580033659, 0.160690652951911, 
0.133731586046578, 0.214985569478799, 0.160690652951911, 0.269932799291976, 
0.339836905918588, 0.242365851038963, 0.214985569478799, 0.677268408841807, 
1.20358829695229), Videogamefrequency = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Monthly", 
"Never", "Weekly", "Yearly"), class = "factor"), Biologicalsex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, interested to hear if you ever found a solution